# DB2 JDBC Windows Authentication

Tags: jdbc, db2, windows-authentication, integrated-security

Looking for example using JDBC on DB2 database using Windows authentication, preferably with db2jcc4.jar driver. Seems like a common enough scenario, but I'm having a hard time finding an example.

Comment: Unclear question. Is your Db2-server also running on MS-Windows? Or is your Db2-server running on Linux but configured to use authentication via Active-Directory?  The IBM jdbc samples for Db2 are in three places, so look more carefully, they are on (1) your Db2 server SAMPLES/jdbc directory (2) in the Db2-Knowledge-Centre online documentation, and (3) on Github.

Comment: To clarify, the DB2 server runs on Windows. I saw the JDBC samples. Most of them appear to use the same Util class to connect: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/java_jdbc/s-Util-java.html. So a few questions: 1. Which specific driver do I need to use if I want to to Windows auth (i.e., authenticate using the account under which my client is running rather than explicitly passing a username/password), 2. Is a DLL required in addition to the driver itself? 3. What do the URL and properties look like to make this connection?

Comment: Imagine I had asked the same question but about MS-SQL instead of DB2, There would be a long list of answers. So really I'm looking for the equivalent DB2 answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question was too vague until you clarified it with a comment asking  how to connect to local Db2-databases via jdbc without a userid/password. So your real question appears to be *"how do I achieve passwordless authentication to local Db2-databases on MS-Windows?"*, which may be a FAQ.

Db2-server delegates authentication to the underlying operating-system services on which the Db2-server is running. Keep in mind that Db2-server runs on a few quite-distinct operating systems, only one of which is MS-Windows.

Yes you can connect via-JDBC to a *local* Db2-database on MS-Windows without specifying a userid/password, using the IBM-supplied jdbc driver.

You can also connect to a *local* Db2-database on MS-Windows via CLI/ODBC and command-line without specifying a userid/password.  When no userid/password is specified then the authentication-ID is that of the currently running session (either the logged on identify, or the `runas` identity).

If you have a *local* Db2-server with a local database running on MS-Windows, then all necessary software is already installed (if using defaults) to achieve the above.

It is important to understand that if the Db2-database is remote from the client then the authentication will need some form of credentials. Such credentials may be in the form of a certificate (if the Db2-database lives on Z/OS), or in the form of a userid/password, or in the form of a kerberos ticket,  or in the form of a token used for cloud-based Db2 etc.

For a **passwordless local jdbc connection** to a Db2-database , you can use the URL format **"jdbc:db2:your_database_name"** .

The class `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver` (as supplied in currently supported versions of `db2jcc4.jar`) supports passwordless connections with that URL pattern.

Example with local database-name = sample.

```
try
{ 
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:sample");
    ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   ...
}
```

The Db2 Knowledge-Centre gives all the details of the available jdbc properties
here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052038.html

Other pages show additional properties that are specific to Z/OS data-sources, or cloud-databases, or i-series data sources, or informix sources etc.

Comment: Clarification: DB2 database is not local. My Java application runs on machine M; DB2 runs on machine N. Both are Windows Servers. In my Java code where I won't be specifying username/password when I connect to the DB. Rather, my expectation is I will be authenticating with DB2 database using the account under which my application is running. Is db2jcc4.jar all I need for this? When setting up connection, do I need to specify a property like integratedSecurity=true (as I would do with MS-SQL).